# how to write a bar chart for the datas in the mysql in java

Tags: java, bar-chart

i have succefully inserted data inside the mysql using xml dom parsing now i want to display the mysql data on my bar chart, so please help with the proper code.

my database has 4 columns, namely "name", "college", "grade", "nature"

so i  have inserted 4 different names and out of 4 names, 2 are sharing the same college. each one are having different grade like good bad and medium. same goes with the grade as well, like first, second, third. So now i need to write the bar chart for this. please help me out.

Comment: Draw a bar chart, or write?

Comment: draw a bar charthttp://stackoverflow.com/users/1820722/joey-rohan

Comment: And that link was for?May be you can use javaFX or swing..to draw..Enough tutorials.Search google.

Comment: i searched it but there is no code which uses mysql. and i am new to this forum.

Comment: You have to collect the raw data i.e the numbers by using a select on the rows.Save the numbers and then draw the chart as you have numbers now.

Comment: thank you for the instant reply, can you help me wit the code if you do not mind, i am not getting any idea, since i am new to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have done an example.

- Extract database values and store in the array's `work[]` and `values[]` .
- Use a container as per your needs
- I have used `JApplet`

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class BarChart extends JApplet
{
    private final  int n=5;
    private String work[];
    private int value[];

    @Override
    public void init()
    {

        work = new String[n];
        value = new int[n];

        work[0] ="name";
        work[1] = "college";
        work[2] = "grade";
        work[3] = "nature";
        work[4] = "extra";

        value[0] = 20;
        value[1] = 10;
        value[2] = 4;
        value[3] = 15;
        value[4] = 5;

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,15);
        g.setFont(font);
        for(int i  = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawString(work[i], 20, i * 50 + 30);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(70, i * 50 + 10, value[i], 40);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(value[i]) + "%", 180, i * 50 + 35);
        }


    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

For your select stmt., I went to google and typed - `select query msql java`
and I got this :

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | date_created        | is_admin | num_points |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+------------+
|  2 | Fred       | Flinstone | 2010-06-23 00:00:00 |        0 |       6000 | 
|  3 | Barney     | Rubble    | 2010-06-23 00:00:00 |        0 |       5000 | 
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+------------+

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * A Java MySQL SELECT statement example.
 * Demonstrates the use of a SQL SELECT statement against a
 * MySQL database, called from a Java program.
 * 
 * Created by Alvin Alexander, http://devdaily.com
 */
public class JavaMysqlSelectExample
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      // create our mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

      // our SQL SELECT query. 
      // if you only need a few columns, specify them by name instead of using "*"
      String query = "SELECT * FROM users";

      // create the java statement
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();

      // execute the query, and get a java resultset
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

      // iterate through the java resultset
      while (rs.next())
      {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
        String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
        Date dateCreated = rs.getDate("date_created");
        boolean isAdmin = rs.getBoolean("is_admin");
        int numPoints = rs.getInt("num_points");

        // print the results
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", id, firstName, lastName, dateCreated, isAdmin, numPoints);
      }
      st.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: God! how i will know what is your dataBase, tables, values..do u know the code how to get make select stmt.?

Comment: you have been a  greatest help and i really appreciate your patience..let me check that.

Comment: now i edited my database to get more clarity, so i have only 2 column now, one is name and other one is grade. name column has "gary" "ray" "chris" and their grade is "first", "second", "first". now i want to draw the bar chart using the above database value, it should be like in the x axis name should be there  and in the y  axis grade should be mentioned.

Comment: @RajeshAcharya You should first check that : `if(grade is second) {marks=2} ` and so on. Then put marks in `value[]` array